# using makehuman how do i attach multiple bvh files to a make human character?

Tags: game-engine

I need a good tutorial on attaching bvh to human mesh made with make human, I am using the game rig bones as skeleton in the figure. I have successfully rigged 1 bvh file to a model and animated it so that is cool!

I need to know, can many animations be put into one skeleton like old unreal PSK's or are many individual animated models each with single animation used to animate a player character's actions all kept in an invisble box attached to character etc...

any help is appreciated I have been using Blender3d for a week and like the results!

Comment: has this anything to do with the Blender game engine (as you tagged it as that)?

Comment: Yes it has anything to do with the game engine. I am using the game engine to build player character models and a game around them of course. do you know anything about this or are you just probing?

Comment: I'm asking as this is a pure Blender task. The BGE does not care about makehuman. As far as I know you need to import bvh and turn them into actions to be used within the BGE. To answer your question (indirectly) you can have several different actions played at a single skeleton as long as at least one bone name matches an animation channel name.

Comment: Thank you for responding, That gives me something to research. I am never sure how much info to blurt out and will write a wall of text if not careful, so I am glad you get what I was asking, thank you again.